# Order Status getting changed automatically

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

I am facing an issue in my site.
The order status is getting changed automatically for several orders.

The issue has been noted mostly for 'canceled' orders.

### Actual Order flow:

New >> Processing >> Canceled

The process should have end there.

But the orders are getting updated automatically.

### New Order flow:

New >> Processing >> Canceled >> Processing

For some orders, we tried changing the status back to Canceled. But still the order gets updated back to 'Processing' status after some days.

New >> Processing >> Canceled >> Processing >> Canceled >> Processing

Is there any feature or setting in the Expresso store to check for the orders and turn the status to 'Processing'.

Can somebody please help me.

Comment: Processing and Canceled are not part of the default order statuses that come with Store. Are you sure you don't have any custom add-ons that are modifying the status of the orders? What versions of EE and Store are you using?

Comment: There's definitely nothing in Store doing this. You either have a custom extension making the change, or a rogue admin changing orders back to 'processing' :)

Comment: Assuming it's a custom extension, you probably want to contact the developer who created it to help you determine the issue, unless you're familiar with add-on development.